# Automatic incrementation with format string

Tags: c#, .net, format, string-formatting

As everyone would be aware the typical way to use the Format method is

```
string res = string.format("<Field Name='Title'>{0}</Field>", "SomeValue");
```

Where `{0}` will become `SomeValue`

And for each subsequent parameter you simply increment the number so the next one might look like this

```
string res = string.format("<Field Name='Title'>{0}</Field><Field Name='FirstName'>{1}</Field>", "SomeValue", "SomeValue1");
```

The problem I am having is that any time I make a change to the parameters in the xml I am trying to build I need to go through and reorder the format string values ie: `{1}` becomes `{2}`, `{2}` becomes `{3}` and so forth.

What I am wondering is if there is some way where I can omit the integer value from the placeholder and the format function might be able to work out the order based on the index of the parameters passed in?

Comment: You should not need to reorder anything in the call to Format, just add the new {2} into the string where you need the new value and put whatever new variable you need to reference for it at the end of the param list.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about a method, but you could use some sort of regex and have it replace based off of named strings instead of indexes, however that is not as pretty.

Another solution would be to just fill your parameters differently. For example, if the 0 spot is changing, then instead of renumbering, just add your new parameter at the beginning of the parameters list instead of just adding it to the end. This will still require a re-write of the code, though.

Lastly, why are you manually formatting the XML, when you can use XMLDocuments and XMLWriters? That will allow you to enter these values in a more controlled way, possibly (I cannot say for sure without seeing the code around it)

Comment: Fair point on everything and I gathered it might not be possible but this is code I have inherited so I don't really want to sit here and rewrite large sections of it. You know what its like...

Answer (score 1):

```
var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>
                 {
                     {"Title", "someTitle"},
                     {"FirstName", "Johnny"},
                     {"LastName", "Depp"}
                 };

var res = string.Join("", fields.Select(kvp => string.Format("<Field Name='{0}'>{1}</Field>",
                                                             kvp.Key,
                                                             kvp.Value)));
```

Comment: If the field value is always the index, you can use string[] instead of Dictionary and fields.Select((field, index) => string.Format("<FieldName='{0}'>{1}</Field>", field, index))

Answer (score 0):

Use a refactoring tool such as Resharper. It will do the reformatting in `String.Format` for you. There is no inherent way to do what you ask.

Resharper will allow you to insert elements in arbitrary places and reorder the indices. It will allow you remove as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)